# cURL Error #: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: ssl, curl, libcurl

In a Windows Server 2019 environment and curl 8.4.0 (Windows) libcurl/8.4.0 Schannel WinIDN

Trying post request (using Postman) from another computer. Getting the following error: "cURL Error #: SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain"
The source(host) and destination(https://api.usps.com/) both have valid certificates and CAs and intermediary CAs. There's nothing self signed.Ours (host/source) are from DigiCert.

I've tried setting CURLOPT_CAINFO and CURLOPT_CAPATH, doesn't change the behavior.

Any suggestions/ideas are welcome.

Comment: Are you sure Postman is using the same libcurl you get from commandline? I believe it has its own, and the specific error text 'self-signed cert in chain' occurs only when using OpenSSL (or LibreSSL) not Schannel. This message really means 'root not trusted' but OpenSSL distinguishes between 'unable to get local issuer' (root not in truststore _or_ received chain) and 'self-signed in chain' (root not in truststore but present in received chain) -- and that host does indeed send the (valid) Digicert root, which like all roots is self-signed. ...

Comment: ... Note 'self-signed' is commonly used -- really misused -- to mean 'signed by me myself or some other ordinary and not very trustworty person' but it actually means 'signed with the same _keypair_ as in the SubjectPublicKeyInfo field'. This applies to certs created with tools like Java `keytool -genkeypair` and `openssl req -newkey -x509` and Powershell `New-Certificate` but also root certs from real, valid, trusted CAs which are created with much more rigorous tools and procedures (see "key ceremony")